# consolidate table td and th query

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two statements that look like this:

```
$('table tr td:nth-child(' + columnNumber + ')').toggle();
$('table tr th:nth-child(' + columnNumber + ')').toggle();
```

Is there a way to combine these two statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A comma.

```
$('table tr td:nth-child(' + rowNumber + '), table tr th:nth-child(' + rowNumber + ')').toggle();
```

jQuery's selectors are the same as CSS (with some stuff added here and there), so all the usual CSS selector rules apply:

```
$("div, h1")  // select div and h1 elements
$("div h1")   // select h1 elements that are nested somewhere within a div
$("div > h1") // select h1 elements that are direct descendants of a div
```

Etc.

By the way, `rowNumber` doesn't make sense; the code will select a given *column*, not a row.